# flutter: how to jump to different pages in different situations?

Tags: flutter

I'm working with flutter recently. I have a `login page`, a `user-protocol page`, and a `home page`. The logic is not complex like below: when I first open the app I haven't log in, I will enter `login page`, then after input my id and password I will jump to `user-protocol page` to read protocol, finish the protocol then jump to `home page`. The problem is if I have log in before, I needn't go to `login page` or `user-protocol page` at a later time, but go to the `home page` directly. So how should I judge if the user login the app for the first time?

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` to store the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store the password.
Every time when you open the app, you can retrieve the password from `SharedPreferences`. If password is empty, go to Login page, otherwise go to Home page.

Comment: yes, this solved my problem. Thanks for your advice.